# How to restart Django-Gunicorn in Docker without downtime

Tags: django, docker, gunicorn

Is there way to restart Django project without downtime.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3.6"

services:
  ### DJANGO 
  web:
    build: .
    restart: always
    command: bash -c "python manage.py migrate && gunicorn tehosmotr.wsgi:application --workers=5 --bind 0.0.0.0:8888"
    volumes:
      - ./django:/code
    ports:
      - "8003:8888"
```

Now i'm restart by this command

```
bash#docker restart django_service
```

and restart takes up to 15 seconds (because of project is really big), so i'm wondering is there way to reload django more softly?

Answer (score 0):

There is, But not Directly from docker commands as I know.

1. Run another instant with your updates.
2. Then you can set up an `nginx` server to redirect traffic from the old containers to the new containers.
3. Then you can peacefully stop the old container, without losing any request with `docker compose stop`

But this will need a lot of configuration. I doubt that this is what you are looking for as this is usually used in a production environment.